# Border in external CSS

Tags: css, border

I am following the instruction of my book and everything is fine, except the border. It's invisible. It doesn't show up on my webpage.
This is my external CSS file:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, verdana, sans-serif;
color: #665544;
padding: 10px;}

page {
border-style: solid;
border-width: medium;
border-color: red; }
page {
background-color: #efefef;
padding: inherit;}
```

Did I make any mistake?
Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: i am sure it should be `.page` instead of `page` :)

Comment: Did that work to solve your problem? If not, then you may need to also change `medium` to a defined value, with units; see "[CSS Values and Units Module Level 3, § 5. Distance Units: the `<length>` type](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#lengths)."

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work. I am going to have a look at that link. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Now, it works. Thanks for your help, guys :)